# How to create a disabled index in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

How to create a disabled index in SQL Server 2008? I could first create the index and then disable it, but that is a waste of time if the table is big. How can I create an index in a disabled state directly?

Background information: I want to have two databases to have identical schema objects but I only need the index in one of the two.

Comment: What is wrong with *not* creating the index in the first place? I mean, you said it yourself that you only need the index in one of the two databases. So, just create it in one and don't in the other.

Comment: I want to come as close as possible to having the schemas identical because I believe it eases maintenance and possibly prevents trouble in the future, that I currently just cannot forsee, but that is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't.  I'm not aware of a way to create an index without having it actually be, you know, **CREATED** when you run the create script.

As a workaround, you could potentially create your desired index with a filter that you know will evaluate false, for instance:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_myindex ON MyTable(myfields)
WHERE PrimaryKeyWhichIsNeverNULL IS NULL
```

THEN disable it, THEN alter it to remove the filter.  I'm not 100% sure this won't rebuild it though.

Comment: [`ALTER INDEX`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) does not allow the definition to be redefined AFAIK?

Answer (score 3):

You can create the index [as a hypothetical index](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_nevarez/archive/2009/11/11/database-engine-tuning-advisor-and-the-query-optimizer.aspx).

```
CREATE INDEX ix ON T(Col)
WITH STATISTICS_ONLY
```

Not sure if that meets your needs?

Comment: Will think about that. Good idea.